# Why a JFrame would not show in a netbeans application context?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, visibility

I'm developing an application over the Netbeans API and I need to show a `JFrame` object. I have already designed this frame in an independent Swing application and it seems to work fine but when I want to import it in my Netbeans application and show it.  It just does nothing.

As far as I know, the code to show a frame is simply:

```
new CustomFrame().setVisible(true);
```

I have also tried to create a new frame straight from Netbeans to see how it reacts with a simple frame.  It lead to the same issue.

Does the Netbeans API have some other requirements to show a `JFrame`?

Comment: *"netbeans API"*  What exactly is that?  JSR 296?  Swing application framework?  Rubber bands?

Comment: @AndrewThompson http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/index.html this api. It's a netbeans platform application using the netbeans api...